# Charge Apple computers bought in USA to use in Europe

Tags: charging, voltage, ac-adapter, europe

I bought an Apple MacBook in the US and would like to use it in Italy. On the cable, it says: 2.5A 125V. What are the possible solutions to charge my computer? Use an adapter, a plug converter or an electric transformer? Someone can explain to me in details? In Italy, the voltage is around 220V, does it damage my pc if I use only a plug adapter?

Comment: All mobile computers (as far as I can tell) for years have been capable of both world voltages since they are designed for travel. Same goes for phone chargers and battery chargers generally. Electrical devices which may not be dual voltage are hair driers and some electric shavers. I work in a backpacker hostel and whenever a circuit breaker goes it invariably turns out to be a travellers hair drier from a 110 volt country in our 240 volt socket.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apple makes their power adapters (cables) so that they will work worldwide (100-240V 50-60Hz) which means that you only need an adapter (plug) and not a converter. Apple [sells a kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB974ZM/B) with the interchangable plugs for each country, but this isn't necessary and you can use any standard adapter.

Have another another look at the power adapter from Apple. Are you sure it only says 125V? If in fact it does not support 220V, then you'll need a converter. Buying a general purpose converter is difficult because it must be suitable for the type of appliance and they can be bulky and heavy. I'd recommend [buying another power adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC556LL/B) from Apple that does support 220V (e.g. 100-240V 50-60Hz) which can be used worldwide.

Comment: The PC I bought does include the power adapter that you linked to: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC556LL/B. There is a cable that connects to this power adapter. As I can read from the cable, it says: "Designed by Apple in California. 01 622-0168 2.5A 125V" if I understand correctly, it does not support 220V. This means that the cable that connects to this power adapter must be changed? Or I can just plug this cable to a normal adapter and it should be fine?

Comment: Most electronic equipment these days is designed to function in the 110-220 V and has autosensing to switch between the two. The plug might be rated for the territory it was bought in, but the equipment itself should work elsewhere. Check any manuals or documentation.

Comment: Most menans - not Apple ( which can sell you tho differents adapters for each system or charge for battery replacement etc. )

Comment: Probably the *cord* says 125V.  Apple power adapters are designed to have the cords swapped out.  My experience (last week I charged my Air in five different countries!) is that the adapter works fine but gets hot quickly in 220V countries.